# How to fix error 'std::promise<int>::promise(const std::promise<int> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to understand 'future', 'promise' and 'async'.  So I copied the following code nearly verbatim from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).  The compiler gives the error `std::promise<int>::promise(const std::promise<int> &)` : attempting to reference a deleted function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
  // future from a packaged_task
  std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){ return 7; }); // wrap the function
  std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
  std::thread(std::move(task)).detach(); // launch on a thread

// future from an async()
  std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return 8; });

// future from a promise
  std::promise<int> p;
  std::future<int> f3 = p.get_future();
  std::thread( [](std::promise<int> p){ p.set_value_at_thread_exit(9); }, //<-- error occurs here
             std::move(p) ).detach();

  std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::flush;
  f1.wait();
  f2.wait();
  f3.wait();
  std::cout << "Done!\nResults are: "
            << f1.get() << ' ' << f2.get() << ' ' << f3.get() << '\n';
}
```

I see why, the 'promise' p can't be copied due to the copy constructor.  But since it is not my class, I can't change it.  So my questions are:

1) This is an example from a C++ reference website, does it compile on any other compiler? (I am using VS 2013).

2) What can I do to fix the error and get the example to work as intended?

NOTE:  I answered my own question below.  But now the example program fails a debug assertion at ...

```
f3.wait();
```

So, though my change allows it to compile, now I have a runtime error.  Is that due to my change?  Or is it another bug?  The error is "Debug Error! ... R6010 - abort() has been called".

NOTE:  I modified my answer below.  I decided to use a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the example that you copied nearly verbatim?

Comment: @molbdnilo - added link

Comment: It compiles as it's supposed to, with clang.

Comment: @Cubbi - but not with VS 2013 default project, how would you set clang with VS 2013

Comment: They are different compilers. If you're interested in getting this fixed, give it.a try with VS2015 and file a bug at Microsoft Connect if it is still not implemented there.

Comment: GCC fails, too, for a different reason.  I just found that cppreference has a choice of compilers to run the example code with.  You are right, it does compile with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just figured it out.  I changed the function to pass a pointer as follows...

```
std::thread( [](std::promise<int>* p){ p->set_value_at_thread_exit(9); }, //<-- pointer fixes error
         &p).detach();
```

I had tried using a reference.  That fixed the original error but then I ran into a failed debug assertion "Debug Error! ... R6010 - abort() has been called".  While debugging, I found the promise destructor being called after the promise task completed but before F3.wait() was called.

So, that answers question #2.  I assume the answer to question #1 is 'no'.  I will let the sight know about the bug (will edit it if I can).

Comment: Iinstead of *letting the site know about the bug*, you can fix it yourself by editing the page.